# Java: Compare string array with a list of strings and call a setter method of the matched word without sorting the list

Tags: java, arrays, list, reflection, matching

A `String[]` needs to be compared with an `ArrayList`.

There is a POJO with `setXXX()` and `getXXX()`. Now the challenge is, if a word from the array matches with a word from the list:

- I need to get the index/position of the matched word.
- I need to get the value from the next index
- I need to call one of the `setXXX()` related with the matched word.

## Fields:

```
String[] s={"email","Email","email_id","Email ID", "Phone","Phone No","Phone Number","Name"};
List<String> valueList=new ArrayList<String>;
```

The `valueList` is populated dynamically from a text file and may contain values like this :

```
<emailID,myemail@gmail.com,ph number,1234567890,name,Ram>
<Email id, myemail123@xxx.com, phone number,4569871230, name,Rahim>
```

if the word "email" is matched, then I should call its `setEmail` method and use the value which is at the next index (i.e. `myemail123@xxx.com`).

## Bean:

```
public class WordBeans{

    private String email,phone,name;
    
    //all the getXXX and setXXX go here.
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post your code and tell us that what have you tried ?

Comment: actually, this is what i have.what I am working on now is, I get text files which contains some fields with their values. But field name are not standard, as i mentioned in the above array email,emailID,email id like this. Now I have to pull out the email id value from the list.

Comment: Use HashSet (so it would be fast) and then use Collection.contains on each element of massive. Knowing idx of element of array you can get next. Simplest way to do your task.

Comment: Well! get started then! If you face problem when actually solving the problem, come back with your code

Comment: cant you normalize the text file before actually processing the data in the file. What i understand is you are trying to build an instance of WordBeans. If thats the case then i suggest you normalize the file. Then read it as Properties. Then do a jackson mapping to get the wordbeans instance.

Comment: why not use regex ? ..